# Rails route dynamic number of segment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, directory

I search to use url like that
/tree/show/folder/subfolder/……/subsubfolder

the content of the page will match the content of a physical folder 
The number of segment can be variable obviously since I can show folder then subfolder then another, then another…… As you can imagine it can be long (and of course I'm aware of the limitation of url length)

I precise that I do not want to show public content (like it was already asked here), but to show a page with information relative to a folder

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcard route globbing. Eg:

`get 'folders/*subfolders', to: 'folders#index'`

This will direct a request for `/folders/subfolder/subsubfolder/subsubfolder/` to `FoldersController#index`, and the called path `subfolder/subsubfolder/subsubsubfolder` will be accessible in `params[:subfolders]`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

Comment: Exactly what I needed, after watching your answer, I indeed found it in the doc, shame on me. thanks :p